# Datatable doesn't refresh correctly after $scope change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, socket.io, angular-datatables

Hi I have a problem with Angular and Datatables. I have a table of items and when a socket.io event comes in, I change the $scope. The problem is, that the datatable change the $scope, but it keeps the first ten items. So e.g. I have 20 items, then I delete one and a socket.io event comes back to tell. The $scope refreshs but the datatable has now 29 items (20 - 1 new items + 10 old items).

Heres my code, mayby somebody has a solution.

btw. sorry for my bad english, hope you understand my problem.

HTML

```
<table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" dt-instance="nested.dtInstance" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Email</th>

                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="tuser in allUser" ng-if="tuser.id != user.id">
                                <td>{{tuser.firstname}} {{tuser.lastname}}</td>
                                <td>{{tuser.email}}</td>

                            </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

And the part of my controller

```
function userCtrl($scope, $http, CSRF_TOKEN, SweetAlert, $location, DTOptionsBuilder, authUser, ws) {

ws.on('connect', function() {
    ws.on('userChange', function (user) {

        $scope.allUser = user;

    });
});

$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
        .withLanguageSource("//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json");

var onUserComplete = function(response) {
        $scope.allUser = response.data;

    };

var getUserData = function() {

    $http.get("/api/getuserlist")
    .then(function successCallback(response) {
        onUserComplete(response);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        getUserData();
    });
}; ......
```

ws is the socket.io service. So the i get the data but refreshing the datatable doesn't work correctly.

Before delete

[image: Before Delete]

After delete

[image]

Thanks for you help

**Edit**

I forgot to say. My socket.io service apply the $scope after changes...

```
module.factory('ws', [ '$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    'use strict';
    var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8890");

    return {
        emit: function (event, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(event, data, function () {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback.apply(null, args);
                        }
                        });
                    });
               },
        on: function (event, callback) {
            socket.on(event, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(null, args);
                });
            });
        },
        off: function (event, callback) {
            socket.removeListener(event, callback);
        }
    };
}]);
```

so I tested it with a normal list and this list do the update. The datatable updated to but keeps the first ten elements and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with

```
 $timeout( function() {$scope.allUser = user;}, 100);
```

thanks to the meanwhile deleted answer.